# Sending thousands of emails from a program?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

A website that I used my password on was compromised and the monkeys in charge had stored everything in plaintext. The list was released publicly online. Needless to say, my password and email were among them.

I would like to send emails to everyone else who was listed (thousands) and inform them that to continue using their password is unsafe. My language of choice would be C# and I would be sending them from my gmail with the help of this code: [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

I can pretty much assume gmail will lock me out before I finish 10 in under a minute. Apart from sending emails out intermittently, how can I do this?

edit: I agree with the responses. I should instead send one email. Is there a limit to the amount of recipients I send an email to from gmail?

Comment: hmm... i'm thinking on offices "bulk letter" functionality VS "I want to write a spam bot" ... go use office

Comment: Gmail is nog ment to be used as an email 'marketing' tool (for bulk operations). They will indeed very likely block you out once detecting you sending a large amount of mailings to unknown contacts. Rather use an email marketing tool like mailchimp.

Comment: Yes there is a limit to Gmail,  I believe it is 100

Comment: @AndrewCetinick, Alright, do you know what I can do?

Comment: [Sending limits](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852)

Comment: If you decide to write one email with a giant recipient list, make sure you add everyone as BCC, so that the recipients don't see each other. Else you would spread the informations, which you are trying to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If happy to spend a bit of money for a reliable solution, you could integrate (very easily) with http://sendgrid.com.  Provides you with heaps of features to track delivery of email and reporting/analysis of email opening, clicking etc.

Gmail does have limitations on how many emails you can send per day, and I would not recommend for your usage.

Answer (score 1):

Or use some online mail marketing tool like MailChimp http://www.mailchimp.com

This service can easily send thousands of e-mails without problems. They have a free service too. Where you can store up to 2,000 subscribers. Send up to 12,000 emails per month.

It even has a REST API available for interacting with it from a custom app.

However I don't know if you are legally allowed to sent e-mails to the addresses on the list. I know it's for a good cause, but please be warned that this sort of e-mails can be considered as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Again, don't build it yourself, but use off-the-shelf specialized services: I suggest looking at

#### [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) (SES)

which is part of Amazon Web Services (cloud storage, computing and more).

- > Amazon SES lets you send bulk and transactional email to customers in a quick and cost-effective manner
- Service highlights include:

  > - Simple
  > - Inexpensive
  > - Reliable
  > - Scalable